# Xamarin create masterdetailpage with multiple detail view using axml(android)

Tags: c#, xamarin.android

I'm new to `Xamarin` framework and developing an application for both iOS and Droid shared application.

I just wanted to make a left slider menu like android normal app using `Masterdetailpage` layout with axml. I couldn't find the proper example or stub for it to develop an structural programming in **Android**.

It would be great help If anyone can suggest any answer.

Comment: axml? Just for android? With XF you could achieve a slider menu for iOS and Android with just one xaml.

Comment: see https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/monodroid/android5.0/NavigationDrawer/